# How do I display a graph with a width of 2000000px on the web side

Tags: canvas, charts, electron

The length of the line graph you want to display is 2160000px. The Y-axis is the value 0-100; The X-axis is time in HH:mm:ss format. That's 25 dots per second. There are 86,400 seconds in a day. =>86400 * 25

#### Existing problem

- The first scheme was to display the picture. Since the img tag could not put down the picture of such a long width, the picture was divided into three parts (2160,000/3). The problem was that the connection between the first and second pictures would be stuck for about one second. And it takes up a lot of memory. So it doesn't work
- Now the scheme used is drawing with canvas, which is of course problematic, because the maximum width of canvas canvas is 6000, so I use three pieces of Mosaic canvas, then listen to the scroll bar below, add the throttling function to constantly update the position of canvas and the content of drawing. This solution meets the requirements, dragging smoothly and memory control. The downside is that the code is very bloated, and the algorithm for refreshing the location is write-dead, and the maintainability is poor.

#### Expect

In addition to the above two schemes, I also found a lot of schemes on the Internet, but they can't reach the expected effect. I hope to find a solution or a library of tools for similar needs.

##### View

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wmnA8.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tace2.png)

Answer (score 0):

```css
.img {
            /* width: 2160000px; */
            width: 300px;
            height: 100px;
            animation: imgtransform 10s infinite;
        }

        .cantainer {
            width: 100%;
            overflow-x: hidden;
        }

        @keyframes imgtransform {
            from {
                transform: translateX(0);
            }

            to {
                transform: translateX(-100%);
            }
        }
```

```html
<div class="cantainer">
  <img class="img" src="https://www.w3docs.com/uploads/media/default/0001/05/805cddb75d8fdc035886bc8d78487eef8b3845bb.png" />
</div>
```

Maybe you can use css animation to achieve this effect.